# Generate hierarchical structure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, recursive

I have a table *employees*

| id | name | manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | susan | null |
| 2 | john | 1 |
| 3 | mary | 1 |
| 4 | josh | 3 |
| 5 | mathew | 4 |
| 6 | leo | 2 |
| 7 | peter | 5 |

I want an output like:

| id | name | hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | susan | null |
| 2 | john | susan->john |
| 3 | mary | susan->mary |
| 4 | josh | susan->mary->josh |
| 5 | mathew | susan->mary->josh->mathew |
| 6 | leo | susan->john->leo |
| 7 | peter | susan->mary->josh->mathew->peter |

DDL:

```
create table employees(id int,name varchar(10), manager int);
insert into employees
values(1,'susan',null)
,(2,'john',1)
,(3,'mary',1)
,(4,'josh',3)
,(5,'mathew',4)
,(6,'leo',2)
,(7,'peter',5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this.

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT
          e.id,
          e.name,
          CAST(e.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS hierarchy,
          e.manager
    FROM  dbo.employees AS e
    WHERE e.manager IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         e.id,
         e.name,
         CAST(ISNULL(c.hierarchy, '') + '->' + ISNULL(e.name, '') AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
         e.manager
    FROM cte AS c
         JOIN dbo.employees AS e ON e.manager = c.id)
SELECT cte.id,
       cte.name,
       CASE WHEN cte.manager IS NOT NULL THEN cte.hierarchy ELSE NULL END AS hierarchy
FROM   cte
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

When you have more then 100 iterations, which your example has not, you need to provide an option: `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)`